# MySQL UNIQUE constraint..How do I fix this bug?

Tags: php, mysql

Firstly, by using Primary key am I applying the UNIQUE constraint properly?

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "oassda", "oas53a") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("o345ja") or die(mysql_error());

// Create a MySQL table in the selected database
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE PersonInfo(
Email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(Email),
 PNumber VARCHAR(45))")
 or die(mysql_error());  

echo "Table Created!";

?>
```

I am trying to make it so Email and PNumber cannot have duplicate rows inserted..But the error I get is "Incorrect column specifier for column 'Email'" apparently this is a bug due to AUTO_INCREMENT only working on INT types....Any idea what to do to make these 2 columns without duplicates ? sorry I am not experienced with MySQL too much as I did it very long time ago and new bugs have developed since then..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456249/how-to-use-unique-index-correctly and also http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a composite primary key?  If so this is the code that will fix your error.

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE PersonInfo(
Email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
 PNumber VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY(Email,PNumber))")
 or die(mysql_error());
```

If not you just want a primary key - **the AUTO_INCREMENT flag is for INT type only**.

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE PersonInfo(
    Email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
     PNumber VARCHAR(45),
    PRIMARY KEY(Email))")
     or die(mysql_error());
```

Or possibly you just need the UNIQUE constraint eg.

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE PersonInfo(
        Email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
         PNumber VARCHAR(45),
        PRIMARY KEY(Email),
        UNIQUE(PNumber))")
         or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont know what comp site is but I guess AUTO_INCREMENT doesnt work for now on anything but INT. Okay thanks it will work :) takes 9 min for my to accept your answer

Comment: Composite primary keys would allow for example a@b.com, 07171717171 and a@b.com, 07272727272 i.e. the uniqueness is across both fields. I think you probably want the last option, which will ensure uniqueness for both fields, independently

Comment: @nadal auto_increment works on NUMERIC types. what's mysql going to do with `president@whitehouse.gov + 1`?

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, using Primary Key you'll have no duplicated email (you're not adding the PNumber field too)
- You are using `AUTO_INCREMENT` on a field that is not an integer (or a sub-type like smallint).

Answer (score 1):

- Take out the AUTO_INCREMENT, it's for integers and makes no sense on a field that you'll be manually populating.
- You don't need NOT NULL since primary key makes it implicit.
- Think about making your fields wider. I have email addrs longer than 45 chars. (I.e., because of TMDA.)

  ```
  CREATE TABLE PersonInfo
  (
      Email VARCHAR(45),
      PNumber VARCHAR(45),
      PRIMARY KEY (Email, PNumber)
  );
  ```